# ¿Como añadir la opcion "footer" en la personalizacion de un tema en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, cms

estoy creando una plantilla y me preguntaba como puedo añadir la opción Footer en la sección Personalizar de Wordpress. Estoy mirando por internet pero no encuentro como hacerlo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿¿Footer es una opción!!!!???  Muestra como o con que estas creando la plantilla para intentar ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería ser posible, para esto tendrás que usar la función $wp_customize, puedes leer mas de eso aquí https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/

Aqui un pequeño ejemplo:

```
function footer_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    
    // Agregar la seccion
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'footer_options', array(
        'title'    => __( 'Footer', 'plugin-name' ),
        'priority' => 130, // Before Additional CSS.
    ) );

    // Agregar los ajustes
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_copyright', array(
        'default'           => '',
        'transport'         => 'refresh',
    ) );

    // Agregar el control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_copyright', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Footer info', 'plugin-name' ),
        'section'     => 'footer_options',
        'type'        => 'textarea',
        'description' => __( 'Copyright info in footer', 'plugin-name' )
    ) );

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'footer_customize_register' );
```

Esto agrega un textarea en el personalizador de wordpress, con eso solo restaría obtenerlo, para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
// obtener el contenido
$footer_copyright = get_theme_mod( 'footer_copyright' );
// Mostrar el contenido
echo $footer_copyright;
```

El primer código va en tu archivo functions.php o plugin de snippets, siempre recomiendo trabajar con un tema hijo, el segundo iría en tu footer del tema, todo depende de como lo estés desarrollando.

Comment: Me funciona todo menos a la hora de llamar al código. Lo he puesto igual que tu y no entiendo porque no me lo muestra. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: @Angel intenta hacer var_dump(); de la variable footer_copyright para ver que valor que devuelve

Comment: me devuelve **false**

Comment: Vale, el problema era que no habia introducido ningun valor. Creia que me iba a devolver un string vacio, no false. Gracias!!